# Errors when installing react-native-cli

Tags: npm, react-native

I'm getting many unmet dependancy warnings and errors when trying to install the react-native-cli. Here is the last bit of the `npm-debug.log`:

```
...
91 warn unmet dependency which is version 0.10.25-1
92 verbose stack Error: The package webpack does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
92 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:103:32
92 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:225:5
92 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:138:5
92 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:251:14
92 verbose stack     at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
92 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:251:14
92 verbose stack     at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
92 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:251:14
92 verbose stack     at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/async-map.js:47:24)
92 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-installed/read-installed.js:251:14
93 verbose cwd /Users/SM
94 error Darwin 11.4.2
95 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-native-cli"
96 error node v0.10.33
97 error npm  v2.1.7
98 error code EPEERINVALID
99 error peerinvalid The package webpack does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
99 error peerinvalid Peer webpack-dev-middleware@1.0.10 wants webpack@1.x
100 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Do you have previous versions of webpack installed? Seems to be a conflict there, maybe try removing webpack and reinstalling the cli.

Comment: Thanks, looks okay on the install now. Still wondering why I get a very long list of warnings for unmet dependancies? Would be helpful to know so I can cleanup a little :)

Comment: I ran "react-native init AwesomeProject" and the result was an incomplete project. All it has in it is a node_modules dir with a react-native dir of contents and then a package.json file. So I'm not able to open "AwesomeProject.xcodeproj" because it does not exist. How can this get working?

Comment: When I ran the "react-native init AwesomeProject" cmd it first warned that I had a higher version of node than it expected. Then it dumped the tree of installs into the react-native dir. Then it complained numerous times about syntax errors in the init file the react-native-cli was producing.

Comment: Solved, after updating Ruby reactive-native projects are now being generated.

Comment: It now looks like the use of Ruby is soon to be deprecated, according to a related issue on the RN site, awesome!